# More pythonic way to find out a number is minimul to all the number

Tags: python, compare, max, minimum

Is there any pythonic way to find out a variable is having a minimum value out of a bunch of variables. for example

```
In [5]: if d<c and d<b and d<a:
   ...:     print "d is minimum.."
   ...:     
d is minimum..
```

Now here only 3 variables are there, So we can do it using and, but what if there are so many variables there to compare ?
please tell me the case of checking at once d is **maximum** or not with all other variables.? 
What about checking d is **equal to all other variables** ? 
**My solution:**

> May be we can add all the variable which needs to be compare in a list
>   and compare them One by one, but I think there must be a better way to
>   do this using python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `all` which will be efficient as it will short-circuit:

```
if all(d < i for i in [1,5,4,4,6,6,4,4,5])
```

Where `i` can be any iterable

Your example would be:

```
if all(d < i for i in (c, b, a))
```

Comment: *sings* "One of these things is not like the other ones ..." (In a good way (+1))

Comment: I suppose I should point out that `i` isn't an iterable in your example ... (still a good answer though)

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the [`min`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) function?

```
if d <= min(c,b,a):
   ...
```

Of course, you can use an iterable as well:

```
if d <= min([c,b,a]):
   ...
```

I like this version because it is **explicit**.  It's very easy to read.  As JonClements points out, there are possibly more efficient ways of doing this for large sets.

Comment: The only problem with this, is that `min` will have to compute the min across its input before comparing to `d` - whereas, d may fail the minimal test on the first element...

Comment: @JonClements -- Yep, that's true.  But it is quite *explicit* about what you're actually doing.  You don't have to think and since readability is important, I think it's still a better answer where performance isn't critical.

Comment: For me the cross-over point, in the best-case scenario where we can short-circuit on the first element, is at a length of about 25.  That fits my experience that for the size of lists that people typically type into SO, forgetting about theoretical efficiency and just making maximal use of C-speed builtins tends to maximize speed, and the algorithmic improvements don't show up until later.

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah, I agree.  I haven't used `timeit` on these, but I imagine there is significant overhead in creating the generator in the first place which is significant for small sets too.  `min` should be reasonably fast and easy to read.  However, I like both solutions in different scenarios (and it appears you feel the same way).

Comment: FWIW I think Jon Clements' answer is _more_ explicit in this case with yours being an assertion that is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=2
>>> b=6
>>> c=5
>>> d=1
>>> d==min(a,b,c,d)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

What's more *Pythonic* than Python's built-in `min` function?

```
f = [a,b,c]
if d < min(f):
    print "d is the minimum"
```

.(..and here are the docs for python's built-in [min](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) function)

If you are seeking for more efficient way you can use `all` function, once you find out that one of the elements is smaller than `d` you stop iterating and return false:

```
if all(d < x for x in a):
    print "d is the minimum"
```